# Insert in a sorted Array-Queue

Tags: java, arrays, queue, sorting

I'm working on sorted Queues like a Priority Queue. I already did it with a List, and it already worked great. Now I'd like to do it with a array. But I have a little logical Problem with add a new Element and insert it into the sorted array.

The final output should be like that:
*Priority: 5 Value: x*
*Priority: 4 Value: iso*
.... (and so on)
So the Element with the highest Priorithy should be on index = 0. 
I just don't know (and yes I know it's really simply to switch it, but I just can't do it :/) how to do it...

I already tried a few things but I'm stuck... :/ can please anyone help?

Here's my code:

```
public class Queue {

private QueueElem[] a;

public Queue(int capacity) 
{
    QueueElem[] tempQueue = new QueueElem[capacity];
    a= tempQueue;
}

public void enqueue(int p, String v) 
{
    QueueElem neu = new QueueElem(p,v);
    int i=0;

        while(i<a.length) 
        {
            if (a[i] == null) 
            {
                a[i] = neu;
                break;
            }   
            i++;
        }
}

public void writeQueue()
{
    int i=0;
    while((i< a.length) && (a[i] != null))
    {
        System.out.println("Priority: " + a[i].priority + " Value: " + a[i].value);
        i++;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Queue neu = new Queue(10);
    neu.enqueue(4,"iso");
    neu.enqueue(2,"abc");
    neu.enqueue(5,"x");
    neu.enqueue(1,"abc");
    neu.enqueue(4,"bap");
    neu.enqueue(2,"xvf");
    neu.enqueue(4,"buep");  
}
 }//end class Queue


class QueueElem {
int priority;
String value = new String();

public QueueElem(){ }

public QueueElem(int p, String v)
{
    this.priority = p;
    this.value = v;
}

public int getPrio()
{
    return this.priority;
}

public String getValue()
{
    return this.value;
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you interpreted your array as a max-heap. That is the typical way to implement priority queue.

What you're looking for, if you're trying to maintain a sorted array for your priority queue, is to implement [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) (sort of; you don't have an unsorted array to start with. You have an empty array that you simply add to, while maintaining a sorted order). Every time you insert a new element, you will iterate through the array to find the correct spot and then insert it there, after shifting the elment currently at that spot, and everything after it one spot down. Note that this is not as performant as implementing this using a heap, since at worst you have `O(n)` performance every time you insert, whereas with a heap you have `O(logn)`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why anyone would want to work with raw arrays... especially now that you have implemented it with a List.

If you want to see how to insert an element in a raw array, look in the code of ArrayList, since underneath it uses a raw array.  You'll have to move all the elements to right of the insertion point, which you could copy in a loop, or by using System.arraycopy().  But the nastiest part is that you will likely have to create a new array since the array size increases by one when you add an element (it depends if you are using an array that has exactly the size of your data, or a larger array, as is done in ArrayList).